# Getting results from solr, making some modifications and then sorting them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

I am using solr to search on Users table.

```
@search = Sunspot.search(User) do
....
end
```

and I get back the results and store them: `@users = @search.results`.

Then I am checking and making some alterations to the results (@users) and finally I want to sort them by weight.

When I do this: `@users = @users.order('weight desc')` I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `order' for #<Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollection:0x000000064a9d58>
```

First of all is ordering possible outside the Sunspot.search block? Any hint/tip is appreciated.

Comment: Outside of the Sunspot-block you'd sort it as you'd normally sort a Ruby structure, and not through the 'order' clause that's sent to Solr

Comment: @MatsLindh Not sure what you mean by "normally sort a Ruby structure"